# Different print result using mozilla on 2 different Operating System

Tags: html, css, printing, operating-system

I've recently been working a web application, this app can handle print method, i use `window.print` of java script to print my document. All is fine when i try on my computer, i use window 7 64B. But when i try on windows xp, i found different result. I have configured all things to make this same with my computer, like format letter, margin on page setup of browser and properties of the printer to. But still not fixed my problem. Any idea? what is the problem? please, i need some advice for this.. thanks

Comment: I think it is not about your operating system. Which browser version are you using?

Comment: i'm using mozilla firefox latest version, v.40.0.3. both, on xp and win 7